# DataOutputStream.writeUTF() problem with UTF signs

Tags: java, utf-8, utf

Hello when my server sends writeUTF("Cześć") (with polish signs),  the client reads this message with DataInputStream.readUTF() and gets "cze[" and why is this a thing, I thought UTF supports polish signs, and also I looked at all UTF characters table and there are ś and ć, so why my client gets this "[" instead of "ść". And also my console prints this message and output is [console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mltan.png)

This project will be chatting app and this is my first phone screen [screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jMuN.png) and you can see that "ść" are supported in this TextView (android way to display text) I am using, and this is my second phone screen [screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw7ha.png)

Comment: Are you sure that console has a font that supports those characters?

Comment: Instead of printing to the console, have the client write to a file, and open the file with an editor which you know supports UTF-8

Comment: can you edit your post adding the way you read these bytes you're sending?

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to be sure that your printing system can show these polish characters.

Anyway you can try to write your bytes to the `OutputStream` without using `DataOutputStream`:

```
String message = "Cześć";
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
byte[] b = message.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
os.write(b);
os.flush();
```

Then you'll need to change the way you read these bytes. A way to do that if your program need to just send messages is to use `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    
String output = "";
String line;
    
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) output += line;
    
reader.close();
    
System.out.println(output);
```

(btw sorry for my bad english)

Comment: ok but my DataInputStream.readUTF can stay? or must I also change it to readByte or something

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that the displaying system must be Unicode-enabled.

Comment: You'll need to change that too. `DataOutputStream` writes the length of the string first. (But I don't think the type of stream is your problem)

Comment: If it's not Unicode-enabled then the 8-byte encoding would have to be something Central European. Those characters are not supported in 'ASCII'. Would have to be something like Windows-1257 or MacCentralEurope